# Shopify Quantity dropdown that fits to stock

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I have a shopify store.  How do I match the quantity dropdown to match the actual quantity in stock.  For example, if there are 3 items, the quantity dropdown should have a max value of 3.  If there are 5 items, then the max value should be 5.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a quantity drop down to your product page, there's a [page in the Shopify docs](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/product-page/how-to-add-quantity-box-to-add-multiple-items-to-cart) that show you how to do this:

```
<label for="quantity">Qty: </label>
<select id="quantity" name="quantity">
{% for i in (1..10) %}
<option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

(Note: Make sure you use `name="quantity"` so the value is passed to the cart.)

The problem with setting the max quantity based on the remaining stock is that the quantity is an attribute of [variants](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/variant#variant-inventory_quantity), not products. If you've only got one variant it will work fine if you change the above for loop to this:

```
{% for i in (1..product.variants.first.inventory_quantity) %}
```

Otherwise, it would be better to limit the quantity in the cart instead. Try this in cart.liquid:

```
<select id="updates_{{ item.id }}" name="updates[]"> 
{% for i in (1..item.variant.inventory_quantity) %}
<option value="{{ i }}"{% if item.quantity == i %} selected{% endif %}>{{ i }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved this functionality to jQuery and removed the liquid from the product page. In other words, I was using an implementation like the one mentioned by Steph Sharp, but came up against the restriction she mentions. My quantity `select` element is now empty:

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity"></select>
```

Using jQuery, I implemented the quantity dropdown that tracks stock thusly:

```
for(var counter = 1; counter <= variant.inventory_quantity; counter++){
  if(counter === 1){
    $('#quantity').empty();
  }
  var newQtyOption = $("<option></option>").val(counter).html(counter);
  $('#quantity').append("<option value='" + counter + "'>" + counter + "</option>")
}
```

This clears the `select` element and then adds a child `option` element for each quantity for this variant. This was built up from Caroline Schnapp's code https://gist.github.com/carolineschnapp/1083007